# How to validate request in json objects - using laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation

My json has two objects one is user_profile and other one is privileges but my validation is working only on user_profile object.

My json:

```
{
    "user_profile": {
        "email": "shahzad11@ovadamd.com",
        "password": "admin123",
        "password_confirmation": "admin123",
        "status": 0,
        "first_name": "Shahzad",
        "middle_name": "Hussain",
        "last_name": "Shah",
        "date_of_birth": "2015-01-01",
        "gender": "M",
        "area_id": 1,
        "address": "Minhatten NY",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "Washington",
        "zip": "12312",
        "fax": "111-111-1111",
        "phone_extension": "2471",
        "work_phone": "111-111-1111",
        "phone_no": "111-111-1111",
        "emergency_contact": "111-111-1111",
        "social_security": "111-11-1111",
        "module_id": 2
        },

    "privileges": {

        "is_super_admin": 1,

      "facilities": [
          {
               "facility_id": 1,
              "is_facility_supervisor": 0,
              "speciality_id": 1,
              "priv_id": "",
              "role_id": 1
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

I want to validate my "privileges" object as well.

My controller:

```php
public function register(Request $request) {

    $body = $request->all();
    $userProfile = $body['user_profile'];
    $userPrev = $body['privileges'];
    $userProfile['is_super_admin'] = $userPrev['is_super_admin'];
    $facilities = $userPrev['facilities'];

    $bodyObj = array_merge($userProfile, $userPrev);
    $validator = UserValidations::validateUser($bodyObj);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
         return response([
             'status' => false,
             'message'   => __('messages.validation_errors'),
             'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()
        ], 200);
    }
```

and my validateUser method:

```php
public static function validateUser($data = [], $update = false) {
    $rules = [
        'first_name'    => 'required|max:25',
        'last_name'     => 'required|max:25',
        "address"       => 'required|max:197',
        "city"          => 'required|max:20',
        "zip"           => 'required|max:5',
        "phone_no"      => 'required|max:12',
        "area_id"      => 'exists:areas,id',
        "phone_extension"   => 'min:3|max:5',
        'gender'        => 'in:M,F,X',
        "work_phone"    => 'max:12',
        "emergency_contact"    => 'max:12',
        "fax"   => "max:12",
        "social_security"      => 'required|max:11',
        "module_id" => 'exists:modules,id',

        // privileges object fields
        "role_id" => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        "facility_id" => 'required',
        "speciality_id" => 'required'
    ];


    if($update) {
        $rules['id'] = 'required|exists:users,id';
    } else {
        $rules['email'] = 'required|email|unique:users';
        $rules['password'] = 'required|min:6';
        $rules['password_confirmation'] = 'required_with:password|min:6|same:password';
    }

    return $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

}
```

How i can put validation on privileges object? 
Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just validate it on a different validator? I do think it would make it more maintainable and scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// privileges object fields
"facilities.*.role_id" => 'required|exists:roles,id',
"facilities.*.facility_id" => 'required',
"facilities.*.speciality_id" => 'required'
```

I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'your rules'])
```

Comment: my objects are not in $request directly i have used $bodyobject in validator and merge my both request

Comment: Why should one do this? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it